# visual studio versions and WEC7 and WEC8

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Well i'm about to decide for visual studio 2012, or 2013.
I do some industrial automation for CE / WEC devices, and in the pas i had to use vs2008.
Now that there is WEC7 and WEC8 i am a bit confused.

Should i go for 2013, or is that like VS2010 not a version that can compile for devices.
I couldnt find this info, apparently 2013 has improvements, but i am not sure if it can do this. 
MS doesnt say it in big words, but i think they create compilers for this only every X generations of visual studio. Also i heard about 2014 is in development, and i feel a bit lost in versions.
Its always quite hard to get such info from MS, or Vendors how they support CE / WEC versions.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit late for your decision but it is now possible to use both Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 for development for Windows Embedded Compact 2013.

See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154234.aspx)